# how do i stop my Formula disk brakes from squealing

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake

I have seen a number of posts about stopping discs from squealing, but mine don't always squeal, when the squealing starts it doesn't stop (as if something has worn off) and it's not worn out pads.

Is it true that some makes and models of discs just squeal? If so, time to change brake manufacturer?

Is it true that different compound pads will make the squealing stop?

Answer (score 7):

Short answer is don't throw out you brakes just yet and a different material MIGHT make the squealing stop.

What you are experiencing is quite typical. Mine are really bad sometimes if they are wet or have dust on them. A few max effort stops fixes it. Steps to address, in a rough order based on cost and hassle factor, and no guarantee of success...

1. Find a nice steep down hill and do a half dozen or more max effort stops from the fastest speed to can get up to. (safety warning bla bla bla). If that does not work, repeat after emptying you water bottle over the disc.
2. Realign the brake calipers
3. Clean the discs with meths/white petrol etc

   1. if you can be bothered trying it, 'burn' the pads
   2. polish the discs and pads with a very fine (400 or 600) wet and dry sand paper
4. Replace the pads with Organic ones.
5. Replace the disc rotors
6. I'm out of suggestion, buy some ear plugs......

Comment: Great summary, covers all the quick fixes, I know of - and +1 for some humour ;)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is squealing can also be caused by micro vibrations, and not necessarily in the brake system itself, for example, due to slightly loose forks. So you might want to check everything is nice and tight.

I had a squeal for a few months out of the blue, then happened to be caught in an enormous downpour, riding through deep and dirty water puddles. The next day (and since) no squeal :)

Answer (score 0):

When mine squeal I

- remove the pads,
- buff with some wet and dry,
- put them back in, and
- re-center the calipers.

It fixes it 9 times out of 10.

Answer (score -1):

Your brakes are leaking fluid, it's getting on the pads. Simple.

Comment: Please consider adding more information to your answer as to why you think this, and also look at the OP's other questions in the post.

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem! I changed to Shimano XTR with ICE Rotors, not a squeal since