# Disc brakes vibrating, "singing" under the rain

Tags: disc-brake, brake-noise

I recently replaced my hubs, and not-so-recently the front brake rotor.

In dry conditions, everything works fine, brakes well and makes almost no noise. In rainy conditions, however, the front disk tends to vibrate and make a huge, horn-like noise.

Is there something wrong with my brake installation that I should fix, or is this normal? I've never experienced such behavior before.

Comment: Pretty normal for auto disk brakes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with brake discs](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/10972/problems-with-brake-discs) and  [how do i stop my Formula disk brakes from squealing](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/17956/how-do-i-stop-my-formula-disk-brakes-from-squealing)

Comment: Indeed, it seems to closely match the second link. Thx!